# DataPager not working with my datasource

Tags: c#, linq

I can't seem to get my datapager to work. Ive been searching for answers and it seems the error I am getting "ListView with id 'searchResults' must have a data source that either implements ICollection or can perform data source paging if AllowPaging is true." is quite common, and usually the answer is to put ToArray() on the DataSource. However I am not sure how to put array on my link statement. Can someone please advise.

```
     searchResults.DataSource = from r in response.Results
        select new
        {
            Title = r[SearchContentProperty.Title],
            Summary = r[SearchContentProperty.HighlightedSummary]
        };

    searchResults.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add ToArray() to your LINQ query try this:

```
 searchResults.DataSource = (from r in response.Results
    select new
    {
        Title = r[SearchContentProperty.Title],
        Summary = r[SearchContentProperty.HighlightedSummary]
    }).ToArray();

searchResults.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
searchResults.DataSource = (from r in response.Results
select new
{
    Title = r[SearchContentProperty.Title],
    Summary = r[SearchContentProperty.HighlightedSummary]
}).ToArray();
```

searchResults.DataBind();
is true,

Edit: i got almost same problem but if still paging is not wotking you can use searchResults PagePropertiesChanging event and write codes like this in to get paging fine

```
protected void searchResults_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender,PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);

//write your codes again to bind data,for this example:


searchResults.DataSource = from r in response.Results
select new
{
    Title = r[SearchContentProperty.Title],
    Summary = r[SearchContentProperty.HighlightedSummary]
 };

 searchResults.DataBind();
}
```